# IRC message parser can't handle URLs

Tags: c#, irc

I'm having an issue parsing IRC data. I have working code for it however when the user includes a URL in the message it get messed up and I can't find a way around it. This is my current code.

```
string message = inputStream.ReadLine();
if (message.Contains("PRIVMSG"))
{
    string[] parms = message.Split(':');
    string userMessage = parms[2];
    return userMessage;
}
```

Example

```
:*****!*****@*****.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #***** :http://www.twitch.tv/
```

It can't grab the full message because of the `http://` part.

Comment: Check for `http:` before you go ahead and Split...

Comment: If it has http or not I need to split it.

Comment: Use an if statement to check if it has http and if it does change how you split, use a regex, or another library for handling urls. If not 'http', proceed as normal.

Comment: **OR** he could just parse the line according to the protocol, instead of toying around with split, regex or what not.

Comment: if you're serious about parsing, use a more complete implementation, i.e. [ircmessagesharp](https://github.com/pdxmholmes/ircmessagesharp)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Internet Relay Chat Protocol (RFC 1459)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-2.3.1), your message (control part at the start) will always start with `:`, as will your params (if you have any - e.g. chat message).

The easiest way to start would be to separate those two components by simply looking for the **first** colon that is not at the start of the line.

```
string example = @":*****!*****@*****.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #***** :http://www.twitch.tv/";
int indexOfColon = example.IndexOf(':', 1);
if (indexOfColon > 0)
{
    string command = example.SubString(0,indexOfColon);
    string message = example.SubString(indexOfColon +1);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wBoKlC

With the same concept, you can parse any part of the line. Here for example you could extract the command (`:PRIVMSG`), username (`!*****`) and host (`@*****.tmi.twitch.tv`) simply by understanding the protocol structure and without and unneccessary `Split` and `Join` or even `RegEx`.

So instead of looking for `PRIVMSG`, you should just parse every line and decide what to do with it later. This line could be troublesome:

```
if (message.Contains("PRIVMSG"))
```

Imagine any other command contained that string (Username, Channel or a regular message). It would totally break your code.

Btw: The 'pseudo' BNF for IRC is:

```
<message>  ::= [':' <prefix> <SPACE> ] <command> <params> <crlf>
<prefix>   ::= <servername> | <nick> [ '!' <user> ] [ '@' <host> ]
<command>  ::= <letter> { <letter> } | <number> <number> <number>
<SPACE>    ::= ' ' { ' ' }
<params>   ::= <SPACE> [ ':' <trailing> | <middle> <params> ]

<middle>   ::= <Any *non-empty* sequence of octets not including SPACE
               or NUL or CR or LF, the first of which may not be ':'>
<trailing> ::= <Any, possibly *empty*, sequence of octets not including
                 NUL or CR or LF>

<crlf>     ::= CR LF
```

Comment: +1. I rolled my own IRC handler for a bot years ago for this very reason. It implemented the whole protocol to prevent the unexpected, such as the command appearing elsewhere as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (message.Contains("PRIVMSG"))
{
    string[] parms = message.Split(':');
    string userMessage = string.Join(":", parms.Skip(2));
    return userMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732237/raw-irc-output-nick-and-message-parsing-via-regex):

```
:(?<nick>[^ ]+?)\!(?<user>[^ ]+?)@(?<host>[^ ]+?) PRIVMSG (?<target>[^ ]+?) :(?<message>.*)
```

The group *message* will have the link:

[image]

Using groups:

```
   var match = Regex.Match(@":*****!*****@*****.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #***** :http://www.twitch.tv/",
            @":(?<nick>[^ ]+?)\!(?<user>[^ ]+?)@(?<host>[^ ]+?) PRIVMSG (?<target>[^ ]+?) :(?<message>.*)");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var message = match.Groups["message"].Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that a web site you are using to display that data for regex?